# How to use IMalloc::Free?

Tags: com, oledb

I'm using ICommandText::GetCommandText method.
According to the MSDN documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709825(v=VS.85).aspx) I need to use IMalloc::Free to release the memory allocated for LPOLESTR   *ppwszCommand output parameter.

How do I use this interface to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass it to [`CoTaskMemFree`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680722(VS.85).aspx), it's wrapping the same default OLE allocator `CoGetMalloc` is exposing.

`CoTaskMemAlloc/Free` are convenient shortcuts to `IMalloc` interface of the default OLE allocator so you can skip the cumbersome interface altogether.

Comment: Cool, but is there any reference confirming that really CoTaskMemFree() is the same as IMalloc::Free()?

Comment: Raymond Chen has an explanation and more on the internals: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/05/173226.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to retrieve an `IMalloc*` pointer first - use [`CoGetMalloc()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693395(VS.85).aspx) for that. Once you've got an `IMalloc*` pointer call [`IMalloc::Free()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693438(VS.85).aspx), passing the address of the block you want to free. Once you've finished with the `IMalloc*` pointer call `IMalloc::Release()` on the pointer or save it somewhere to reuse and free when you no longer need it.