# escape space in connection string

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, ado

I am trying to connect to a SQL server database using ADO. The password contains a space as the last character. When building the connection string, how should I escape the password?

MSDN says put it in single or double quotes but that does not seem to be working...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx

This is what my connection string looks like:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=master;Data Source=test;uid=john;pwd="123 "
```

Thanks

Comment: Can we see a similar version of your connection string, please?

Comment: should the pwd contain a space?

Comment: `The password contains a space as the last character.` Why, why, why, why, why? Many interfaces will ltrim/rtrim strings. This seems silly to try to work around this when you should simply use a better password.

Comment: @Aaron, what workaround ? You should fix such trimming interfaces instead. I would definitely let user choose whatever password he/she wants, however it's crazy. I haven't met this (since I'm not using such password), but how this system would work ? After you press register or create user, a popup with *"Sorry, you can't use spaces around your password"* would popup ? Yes, forbid the space character might be a workaround.

Comment: @TLama you don't have control over all of those interfaces. And when you don't, yes, you should validate and prevent such characters from being included in a password. In this case it's not a real user's password, it's the application password, so I don't understand why the password needs to end with a trailing space.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Why not? It's up to the user to decide what the password will be. The real question is WHY these "many interfaces"  do trim? Also I don't see any problem with a password with blank(s) at the end or beginning.

Comment: @iPath so are you up in arms with Apple because iTunes won't let you have a password with three consecutive characters that are the same? What about services that max out the password at 12 characters, or don't allow # or $ or _? Would you like to also allow carriage returns, line feeds, tabs and non-printing boxes into passwords? Different services have different reasons for their password rules. I didn't come up with them, but I know that if I had some reason to have a trailing space, and a service didn't allow it, I would get over it and use something better. Period.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can tell you what **does** work:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Password="123 ";Persist Security Info=True;User ID=john;Initial Catalog=mydbname;Data Source=127.0.0.1
```

1. When `pwd` keyword is used instead of `Password` it fails to connect - You need to use `Password` keyword which should be enclosed with double-quotes.
2. `uid` instead of `User ID` works just fine - Id'e still use `User ID` because the connection builder creates it by default.
3. `Persist Security Info` keyword (was mentioned in one of the comments) has no impact on connection - As @TLama well commented *"You can connect, but you don't get the password back from the `IDBProperties` interface, if you keep it False."*
4. The order of keywords in the connection-string is not important. the `IDBProperties` interface parses this string into an [internal "Properties" collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15237234/937125)

---

Tested with SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: You changed two things. You changed the name of the value from `pwd` to `Password`, but you also moved the value so it's not at the end of the string anymore. Are both changes necessary?