# Alternatives to IMalloc_Free and IMalloc_release

Tags: c++, c, winapi, header-files, atl

For freeing memory used by the `SHGetFolderLocation()` API, I use `IMallloc_Free()` and `IMalloc_Release()`.

This compiles fine when including

```cpp
#define COBJMACROS
#define CINTERFACE
```

However, in some files, specifically ATL header included files, this results in compiler issues. However, there `pMalloc->Free()` and `pMalloc-Release()` work.

Is there any free and release method which works for both of these files?

Comment: The `COBJMACROS` macro enables convenience wrappers for access to COM objects from C. If that conflicts with other code you can look into the convenience wrapper and find the expanded version on the right-hand side.

Comment: Use CoTaskMemFree for everything allocated by the Shell. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cotaskmemfree

Comment: `SHGetFolderLocation(..., &pidl); ...; CoTaskMemFree(pidl);` forget about IMalloc completely

Comment: @Sha3003 the documentation tells you how to call CoTaskMemFree

Answer (score 2):

Generally no, you either use C way to work with COM, or C++ way.

Specifically for `IMalloc` here, however, just use `CoTaskMemFree` instead. Default `IMalloc` and `CoTaskMemFree` are compatible, and COM does its allocations compatible with them.

[`SHGetFolderLocation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderlocation) is documented to be deallocated with `ILFree`, but see remark in [ILFree documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-ilfree#remarks).

See also [How to use IMalloc::Free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079508/how-to-use-imallocfree). The [linked post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040705-00/?p=38573) explains that in older systems shell allocation could be incompatible with COM allocation, so you could not use `IMalloc::Free` or `CoTaskMemFree` for `ILFree`, but now you can (assuming you don't support historic OSes).